# Source in my SSIS package isn't picking the float values with preceding zeros

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have a package which takes source as a text file and there is an `ARTICLE` column in the source. It is numeric and in the destination it's float, so if a value comes 0000123 it goes into the destination like 123 (truncates preceding zeros).

However, in the same package a different column has same stuff. Numeric source and float destination but when this column value in the source has preceding zeros, it fails.

Example -

- 123 will be loaded into the destination
- 0123 will not be recognized and it will fail at source

Can anyone of you help me here please? How do I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed that the columns that are failing do not have any leading or trailing "white space"

This will cause the column to fail if it is trying to convert numeric as white space is unrecognized.